# emails sent but not received

Tags: php, email

i'm working in new website but i'm facing problem which is the emails sent from contact-us page not received..
i think that the form send email to different address.
i need help to modify the page code to sent email to specific address 
any one can help ?

```html
<?php
$this->dispatch("layout/header_logout/3");
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<?php

$validate=array(
  "name"=>array(
  "notNull"=>array($this->get_message("not null"))
  ),
  "email"=>array(
  "notNull"=>array($this->get_message("not null")),
  "isEmail"=>array($this->get_message("invalid email address"))
  ),
  "subject"=>array(
  "notNull"=>array($this->get_message("not null"))
  ),
  "description"=>array(
  "notNull"=>array($this->get_message("not null"))
  )
  
  
  
);


 $advseo=$this->get_seo_name('index/advertiser');
      
      if($advseo !='')
      $advurl=BASE.$advseo;
      else 
      $advurl=$this->make_url("index/advertiser");


 $pubseo=$this->get_seo_name('index/publisher');
      
      if($pubseo !='')
      $puburl=BASE.$pubseo;
      else
      $puburl=$this->make_url("index/publisher");
      


?>

<div class="header_div">
<div class="container">

<h2 class="page_header"><?php echo $this->get_label('contact us');?></h2> <span class="span_link"><a  href="<?php echo BASE;?>"><?php echo $this->get_label('home');?></a> / <a href="<?php echo $advurl;?>"><?php echo $this->get_label('advertiser');?></a> / <a href="<?php echo $puburl;?>"><?php echo $this->get_label('publisher');?></a> </span>

</div>
</div>


<section>
        

            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <div class="row">
<?php 
$form=$this->create_form();
$form->start("contactus","","post",$validate); 

$recaptcha_public_key=$this->get_variable("recaptcha_public_key");
?>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12" >

<div>
  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo $this->get_label('name');?> <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $this->get_variable("name");?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo $this->get_label('email');?> <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $this->get_variable("email");?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo $this->get_label('subject');?> <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                            <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="<?php echo $this->get_variable("subject");?>" class="form-control" required>
                        </div> 
                        
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo $this->get_label('description');?> <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                            <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="12" cols="39"  class="form-control" style="height: 75px !important;"><?php echo $this->get_variable("description");?></textarea>
                        </div> 
                        
                        
                        <?php if(Configuration::get_instance()->read('enable_captcha_verification')==1){?> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><?php echo $this->get_label('image verification');?> <span class="compulsory">*</span></label>
                            <?php echo recaptcha_get_html($recaptcha_public_key);?>
                        </div> 
                        <?php }?>   
                           
                           
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" value ="<?php echo $this->get_label('send mail');?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">SEND MAIL</button>
                        </div>   
                           
                   </div></div>
<?php $form->end(); ?>

<?php if(Configuration::get_instance()->read('admin_address') !=""){?>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<div>
<div class="form-group"><label><?php echo $this->get_label('company location',array('x'=>Configuration::get_instance()->read('admin_address')));?></label>
<div id="mapDisplay" style="display:none ;width: 100%;height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php }?>

</div>
</div></div></div>
</section>



<script type="text/javascript">
var map,lat,lng;
function initialize() {
 
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
 var myOptions = {
             zoom: 10,
             center: myLatlng,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDisplay'), myOptions);

  $('#mapDisplay').show();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  map.setCenter(myLatlng);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: myLatlng,
         map: map
     });
     
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: "<?php echo Configuration::get_instance()->read('admin_address');?>",
   maxWidth:233,
   });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });
    
  
}

$(document).ready(function() {

 lat="";
 lng="";
 addrstr='<?php echo Configuration::get_instance()->read('admin_address');?>';

 if(addrstr !="")
 {
      var geocoder =  new google.maps.Geocoder();
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address':addrstr}, function(results, status)
      {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
       {
        lat=results[0].geometry.location.lat();
     lng=results[0].geometry.location.lng(); 
     initialize();
       }
      });
 }
});
</script>

<?php $this->dispatch("layout/footer");?>
```

Comment: use static value in email field then check.

Comment: You'll need to show the backend code.